# 0-1А adjustable current source IC for dimming battery powered LED

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, current-source, battery-operated

I'd like to build an adjustable current source for battery-powered LED lamp to dim it so I can adjust its brightness for reading while using it.

It is originally powered by 4V 0.75А PSU but consumes about 500mA max.
I want to power it from a 1S Li-Ion so would be 3-4.2V as well.

I guess linear regulator is a bad choice for that.

But I have troubles to find a switching IC myself googling because some of ICs are too rare, some are not too friendly to be soldered by amateur (DIP/SOIC/TO would be OK), some require too many discrete components.

Could you please recommend me some good old, simple, but efficient chip/solution?

Comment: Do you want the LED current to be variable? Or do you just want to reduce the LED current to a lower level?

Comment: I want it to be variable to adjust brightness for reading. Thank you, I'll update the question.

Comment: Li-ion is 3-4.2V (mostly 3.7v), not 4-5V

Comment: In that case, you could do it using a linear regulator, just make the output voltage adjustable across the LED's forward voltage range. Not as efficient as a PWM regulator, but it works.

Comment: Using voltage control for LEDs is not great (https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3256)

Comment: A tip: instead of building your own switched regulator using some IC, get a **ready-built module**. These are only a few $$ on ebay and you will prevent having issues (which you will have with your own design). Some have a potmeter to adjust the voltage and/or current, this might be suitable to use for dimming.

Comment: Bimpelrekkie, I had one (LM2596?) but it starts from 7V only because of big drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting LED brightness is a very common problem, and there are a lot of ready-made solutions. If you want, you could roll your own with a simple mosfet and PWM with a microcontroller, or you could go down the route of using a monolithic IC to do it.

If using an IC, you can either go for linear (not really recommended because you'll be dumping a fair amount of heat) or a switched mode like [mic2298](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic2298.pdf).

You could also just buy one like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-LM2596-LED-Driver-DC-DC-Step-down-Adjustable-CC-CV-Power-Supply-Module/142659997757?hash=item213732d03d:g:3VMAAOSwZKBZNQ2Y). You'll probably want to switch their potentiometer with a nicer one.

Comment: Thanks. The last module didn't work for me because starts from 7V (on my load).

Comment: Thanks, I decided to get uC + PWM and mosfet (IRLML6244TRPBF particurarly - uC powered from 3.3V)